# Hiding actionbar menu items, phone vs. tablet

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've just started developing an app which will have a list of items and a detailed view of each item, so I've set out different phone and tablet layouts using fragments. There's also a navigation drawer, and I'd like one of the options in the menu to only show when the detail view fragment is on screen and to be hidden when the navigation drawer is open. So, I did it like this:

1. Main view creates the menu.
2. Detail view fragment adds the specific detail view option (a share button, "action_share").
3. Opening the navigation drawer runs this in onCreateOptionsMenu in the navigation drawer fragment:

   ```
   if (menu.findItem(R.id.action_share) != null)
   {
       MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
       item.setVisible(false);
       getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This works on a tablet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
   {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "...but not on a phone.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```

This works as expected on the tablet but on a phone the action_share menu item isn't detected.  The layouts differ as follows.

Phone:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout> <!-- list and detail fragments are swapped in here -->
    <fragment> <!-- navigation drawer -->
</DrawerLayout>
```

Tablet:

```
<DrawerLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       <fragment> <!-- list fragment -->
       <fragment> <!-- detail fragment -->
   </LinearLayout>
   <fragment> <!-- navigation drawer -->
</DrawerLayout>
```

The hierarchy viewer shows a slightly different arrangement for each.

Phone:

`LinearLayout -> ActionBarContainer -> ActionBarView -> ActionMenuView -> ActionMenuItemView (action_share)`

Tablet:

`ActionBarOverlayLayout -> LinearLayout -> ActionBarContainer -> ActionBarView -> ActionMenuView -> ActionMenuItemView (action_share)`

So, can anyone suggest why the action_share menu item is detected in one layout and not the other, and what I might do to fix this?

EDIT:

Further investigation shows that `menu.findItem()` isn't picking up the action_share menu item on the phone, but `findViewById()` is, which is very odd. Of course, I can't do anything with the latter as I can't cast it to a MenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code to find and toggle the visibility status of the share button only works when it is put in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` rather than in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. This doesn't explain why the tablet layout wasn't affected, but at least both layouts now work as they should now that I have added `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and moved the relevant code to it.